# Tensorboard in aws batch docker container

Tags: docker, tensorflow, containers, tensorboard, aws-batch

I am running a aws batch service, containing tensorflow code in a docker file. I can see that the code executes, but, the problem is I want to get the tensorboard access url so that I can access it in my local browser.

I am confused, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Batch doesn't allow you to expose ports.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245323

The ideal use case for Batch is to run massively horizontally scalable jobs. They should also die as soon as the work is finished.

If you are just running 1 off jobs or testing things and need access to a web interface, you are prob better off just running an EC2 instance with the AMI and Docker Image on it.

That way you can expose ports via a security group, and control keeping the container alive after it does work.